# R str_extract strange behavior in loop

Tags: r, regex, for-loop

**Greater Goal**

I want to extract package names (and more details later) from the package bibliography in R (generated with `write_bib()`). In order to create a table with columns for the most relevant information on the packages used in my analyses (e.g. Name of the package, version, maintainer, citation).

In the example entry from the bibliography below, I want to get the following string `R-base`

> "@Manual{R-base,   title = {R: A Language and Environment for
> Statistical Computing},   author = {{R Core Team}},   organization =
> {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},   address = {Vienna,
> Austria},   year = {2020},   url = {https://www.R-project.org/},   }"

The extraction of a the packagename substring between `{` and `,` works
with the regex `""(?<=\\{).*(?=,)"` -> this returns `R-base`

**Current problem**

When outside of a loop, the code below results the desired output of `R-Base`

```
  teststring <- "@Manual{R-base,
  title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
  author = {{R Core Team}},
  organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
  address = {Vienna, Austria},
  year = {2020},
  url = {https://www.R-project.org/},
  }"
  
  str_extract(teststring,"(?<=\\{).*(?=,)")
```

However when I try to do the exactly same thing inside of a for loop
I get multiple matches from the `str_extract()` function.

```
bibliography <- write_bib()
  for (entry in bibliography[1]){
  # currently for testing purposes just for the first entry in bibliography
    print(typeof(entry))
    print(str_extract(entry,"(?<=\\{).*(?=,)")  )
  }

[1] "character"
[1] "R-base"                                                  
[2] "R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing}"
[3] "{R Core Team}}"                                          
[4] "R Foundation for Statistical Computing}"                 
[5] "Vienna, Austria}"                                        
[6] "2020}"                                                   
[7] "https://www.R-project.org/}"                             
[8] NA                                                        
[9] NA
```

Which is strange to me. I also included typeof for validation purposes. However the character vector `entry` in the loop should be identical to `teststring`

#### Edit

Found the solution has to do with list, in bibliography as obtained by `write_bib()`
Specifiying which element solved it somehow.

```
name <- str_extract(entry[1],"(?<=\\{).*(?=,)")
```

Comment: Where is the library located? How did you install it? Also, why did you use a loop here?

Comment: Because I want to iterate over all packages I have loaded in my script. I forgot one line in the code above, I will edit it.

Comment: Please try `res <- sapply( bibliography, function(x) str_extract(paste(x, collapse="\n"), "(?<=\\{).*(?=,)") )`, then `names(res) <- NULL` and check the `res`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
library(knitr)
bibliography <- write_bib()
res <- sapply( bibliography, function(x) str_extract(paste(x, collapse="\n"), "(?<=\\{).*(?=,)") )
```

I get

```
[1] "R-base"    "R-knitr"   "knitr2015" "knitr2014"
```